# ¿error operar en c++?

Tags: c++, c

necesito conectar mi programa en c++ con una base de datos,pero para ello la base de datos me pide que convierta mis direcciones ips en un numero ip pero al hacerlo en c++ me aparece un fallo,creo que se debe al tamaño máximo que puede guardar las variables,aquí esta una imagen de como se hace y mi código en menor escala

[image: convertir en numero ip]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
  long convert = 0;
  int n1;
  int n2;
  int n3;
  int n4;
  


  cout<<"ingrese la direccion IP 1 octeto:";
  cin>>n1;
  cout<<"ingrese la direccion IP 2 octeto:";
  cin>>n2;
  cout<<"ingrese la direccion IP 3 octeto:";
  cin>>n3;
  cout<<"ingrese la direccion IP 4 octeto:";
  cin>>n4;
 
 

  long r1 =16777216*n1;
  long r2 =65536*n2;
  long r3 =256*n3;
  
  convert = r1+r2+r3+n4;
  cout<<"el numero IP es:";
  cout<<convert<<endl;
  cout<<"1 parte";
  cout<<r1;
  cout<<"2 parte";
  cout<<r2;
  cout<<"3 parte";
  cout<<r3;


    return 0;
 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué fallo "*te aparece*"?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster no me aparece un error lógico,funciona pero da un valor que no corresponde,un negativo

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ya adjunte el "error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> creo que se debe al tamaño máximo que puede guardar las variables

El resultado de:

```
long r1 =16777216*n1;
```

Cuando `n1` es igual a `202`, es `3388997632`. Compáralo con el valor máximo que puede guardar un entero de 32 bits, que es `2147483647`, y podrás ver que tu teoría es correcta.

Recuerda que `long` no siempre es mas grande que `int`, la única garantía que tienes es que tiene al menos 32 bits. [Referencia](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

Puedes probar si `long` tiene el mismo tamaño que `int` en tu sistema con el siguiente código.

```
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long));
```

Siendo que el problema que tus variables son muy pequeñas, la solución es sencilla, usa variables mas grades:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int64_t convert = 0;
    int64_t n1;
    int64_t n2;
    int64_t n3;
    int64_t n4;

    cout << "ingrese la direccion IP 1 octeto:";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "ingrese la direccion IP 2 octeto:";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "ingrese la direccion IP 3 octeto:";
    cin >> n3;
    cout << "ingrese la direccion IP 4 octeto:";
    cin >> n4;

    std::cout << n1 << '.' << n2 << '.' << n3 << '.' << n4 << '\n';

    int64_t r1 = 16777216LL * n1;
    int64_t r2 = 65536LL * n2;
    int64_t r3 = 256LL * n3;

    convert = r1 + r2 + r3 + n4;
    cout << "el numero IP es:";
    cout << convert << endl;
    cout << "1 parte: ";
    cout << r1 << '\n';
    cout << "2 parte: ";
    cout << r2 << '\n';
    cout << "3 parte: ";
    cout << r3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: gracias ya puedo hacer mis consultas en la base de datos

Comment: También puedes usar un `uint32_t` y te alcanza perfecto